# Clickable links to py.test stack frame lines in compilation-mode

Tags: python, compilation-mode

In `compilation-mode`, how can I make the default py.test output have clickable links to source code (when using py.test's default formatting of tracebacks)?

Does somebody already have appropriate `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` entries?

Comment: How do you run your tests ? I have all of this when running pytests and I thought it's the default behaviour of compilation-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `py.test` should automatically do it. Go to any directory or python file, run `M-x compile RET py.test RET`, you will get colorized output and traceback with hyperlinks like this.

[image]

It is better to use elpy as it provides better integration with test runners.

Comment: A note: elpy's py.test integration is a bit more convenient, for example one can run the current unit test the point is in, switch venvs, etc.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that!  Armed with that knowledge, I see that, unknown to me, somehow I'd ended up with `cmake` and `cmake-info` customized into the middle of my `compilation-error-regexp-alist`, which breaks that.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove the other half, will ask that in a new question