# How to syntax-colour py.test output?

Tags: python, faces, font-lock, syntax-highlighting, compilation-mode

In `compilation-mode` (or some similar mode), how can I make the default py.test output be colourized?

I'm not talking about [clickable links](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31554/clickable-links-to-py-test-stack-frame-lines-in-compilation-mode), but about just 'syntax' colouring the various parts of the output.  Scare quotes because there are multiple syntaxes going on in the same buffer (python code snippets, various kinds of stack info, and other py.test output like the 'FAILURES' line), and because py.test's output perhaps isn't that standardized.

I'd be happy with just some of this structure highlighted, but the more the merrier.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this accomplished by modifying `compilation-mode-font-lock-keywords` and `compilation-error-regexp-alist(-alist)?`. If py-test is running in a raw `compilation-mode` than the appropriate alists need to be added to the global font-lock-keywords & error-regexp-alists for compilation-mode.

However I believe when defining a compilation derived mode with `define-compilation-mode`, it automatically references a variable for deriving mode specific error and font-lock information. IE

```
(define-compilation-mode pytest-compilation-mode "Pytest Compilation" "docs.")
```

Automatically generates a references to variables like:

- `pytest-compilation-error-regexp-alist`
- `pytest-compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`
- `pytest-compilation-mode-font-lock-keywords`

I believe for this example it would be a `pytest-compilation-mode-font-lock-keywords` which would cover metadata about the buffer like number of errors, if it finished, the same as `compilation-mode-font-lock-keywords` does in the `compile` library. Similarly `compilation-error-regexp-alist` defines what errors look like (as well as hyperlink formatting, etc). Finally `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` defines how to map to lines referenced within a given error. I recommend reading through the documentation for `compile` using `M-x locate-library compile` for more details.